# HTMLAgilityPack how to parse document that is already open in WebControl

Tags: c#, html, dom, html-agility-pack

How do I parse a table in a page that is already open in WebControl? (I don't want to reload the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webcControl.DocumentText);
```